# getting exit code error when install any new pod

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

i getting exit code error when i try to install any new pod and that's never happend

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/hamadaraouf/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/بورسعيد-eypkqarpocnxxwbqicnkmsfprobc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DTGradientButton'
>   ld: framework not found DTGradientButton
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arwos.png][1]

thank you

Comment: Try cleaning project by command+shift+k or delete the derived data. By the way which pod you are trying to install?

Comment: already did that but dosn't work with me

Comment: clean the project with command + shift + option + k , then Remove all pods and install it again

Comment: Delete derive data and quit xcode and try again for the same.

Comment: am sorry but i did that also